# Finding and updating object based on a type using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I’m trying to check the values in a nested object and replace them if necessary. Using reflection I can iterate through all the nested objects and get the property types but I’m stuck retrieving the values and replacing the values. I threw together a simple example.

Say I have the following model:

```
public class Employee
{
    #region Members
    private string _FirstName;
    private string _LastName;
    private StreetAddress _EmployeeAddress;
    #endregion
    #region Properties
    public string FirstName { get { return _FirstName; } set { value = _FirstName; } }
    public string LastName { get { return _LastName; } set { value = _LastName; } }
    public StreetAddress EmployeeAddress { get { return _EmployeeAddress; } set { value = _EmployeeAddress; } }
    #endregion
}

public class StreetAddress
{
    #region Members
    private string _Street;
    private string _City;
    private string _State;
    private string _Zip;
    #endregion
    #region Properties
    public string Street { get { return _Street; } set { value = _Street; } }
    public string City { get { return _City; } set { value = _City; } }
    public string State { get { return _State; } set { value = _State; } }
    public string Zip { get { return _Zip; } set { value = _Zip; } }
    #endregion
}
```

In my scenario I need to update the **Street** in **StreetAddress** from *“123 Main Street”* to *“999 Main Street”* for any object that **StreetAddress** appears in. The **StreetAddress** object could appear in any level of any give object.
So let’s say I have **Employee** cast as an object and I’m using the following to iterate through the **Employee** object looking for the **StreetAddress** type.

```
private static void ReadPropertiesRecursive2(Type type)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
    {

        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(StreetAddress))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(property.Name);

            Type StreetAddressType = property.GetType();

            //Get the value of 'Street'  
            //Here is where I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the value

            Debug.WriteLine(StreetAddressType.GetProperty("Street").GetValue(StreetAddressType, null));
            //The above throws the Exception: 'System.Reflection.TargetException'

            //Check the value of 'Street'

            //Replace the value of 'Street'

        }
        if (property.PropertyType.IsClass)
        {
            ReadPropertiesRecursive2(property.PropertyType);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ReadPropertiesRecursive2(Employee.GetType());
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing in the syntax to use the 1) return the value of and 2) update the value if necessary. If you could point me in right direction, that would be awesome or if there is a better method I'd be interested to know about it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fearing that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), can I ask why you need to do this using reflection?

Comment: Agree - unless this is just an experiment to figure out how reflection works, it's almost certainly better not to do whatever this is using reflection. When you use your properties and methods the "normal" way, then whenever you're trying to do something wrong you'll get a compiler error. That's good because it's easy to fix. With reflection you'll get a runtime error because until the program runs it can't tell what will or won't work. Reflection is there when we need it but it's not supposed to be how we use our classes under normal circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone.It seems I'm trying to solve a number of specific problems with one generic solution where I should be taking a safer, more strongly typed route. The reason I went for reflection is that my object type is unknown at the time. I appreciate everyone's input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you could point me in right direction, that would be awesome or if there is a better method I'd be interested to know about it.

This answer falls more into the 'pointing in the right direction' category.

It appears that you want to update the street address on various entities which may contain an instance of `StreetAddress` somewhere in their structure, perhaps nested several levels deep.

The fundamental problem with this is that our code should be written to interact with specific properties of specific classes. We need to know which property we want to update and update that property, not just update any property that looks like it might be the right one because it's of a certain type.

Consider this example:

```
public class Employee
{
    public StreetAddress Address {get;set;}
    public EmergencyContact EmergencyContact {get;set;}
}

public class EmergencyContact
{
    public StreetAddress Address {get;set;}
}
```

If you update an address the "normal" way:

```
employee.StreetAddress = updatedAddress;
```

or

```
employee.EmergencyContact.StreetAddress = updatedAddress;
```

then you're fine.

But if you do something like this:

```
UpdateStreetAddress(object something, "123 Maple St.")
```

...and then it goes looking for every `StreetAddress`, it's going to update *every* `StreetAddress` anywhere in that object. It will set both the employee's address and the employee's emergency contact's address.

It's not worth it trying to write a "one-size-fits-all" method that does this for every class. It's much better to just write code that updates exactly what you need to update. It's okay if it's a little bit more code (although it probably won't be.) You'll get that time back by not dealing with defects, unexpected side effects, and future developers not having to figure out what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest problem is that `GetValue` needs an *actual object* to get the value of. The `PropertyInfo` and for that matter, the `Type` is just *metadata*. In other words, a valid use of `GetValue` looks like:

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
PropertyInfo addressProp = typeof(Employee).GetProperty("StreetAddress");
string address = addressProp.GetValue(emp);
```

(Passing `null` tries to get it off the `static` "instance" for what its worth)

Refactor your code to get and set off of the actual instance and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you are feeding in a type of object, but not the object itself.

When you provide the argument as

```
ReadPropertiesRecursive2(Employee.GetType());
```

You are not providing the Employee object itself, instead you are providing the 'type' of object.
So when you ask it to read the value of those properties, it is going to say 'Read this property or field on what object?'

```
StreetAddressType.GetProperty("Street").GetValue(StreetAddressType, null);
```

The null above, needs to be the actual object you are processing.
Change your method signature to:

```
private static void ReadPropertiesRecursive2(Type type, object obj)
```

Then feed your actual object that holds the data in as the second argument.

You might then be able to perform:

```
StreetAddressType.GetProperty("Street").GetValue(StreetAddressType, obj);
```

As now you will be telling it to read the 'Street' field on the obj object.